# ndde c# with excel stopped working

Tags: dde

I use the ndde (dynamic data exchange) in https://ndde.codeplex.com/ to exchange real-time data between my c# application and Excel. 
My C# application have a datagrid of about 100 columns and 180 rows and the grid data are updated continuous. 
my problem is when I take all the columns to excel in dde format to exchange data, the excel is stopped working. but when I take less columns about 70 only, it works well.

How to overcome that?